# Insert value into list after end of list

Tags: c#, arrays, list

In a C# program I'm creating, I have a multidimensional list that I have created using the code `List<List<long>> NumList = new List<List<long>>()` that stores calculated values at an index of the result. An example of its output should be:

```
{
    3: {
        5577
    },
    6: {
        348,
        157
    },
    7: {
        999999999999
    }
}
```

The code gets the length of the number, converted to words, then gets the chain length for bringing the word to four, for example, `5577` = `five thousand five hundred seventy seven` which is 40 characters long, so then it gets `forty` which is 5 characters long, which is `five`, four characters long and ending the chain.

The function I created goes through every number from an inputted number to zero, calculates the word chain length and returns the longest chain as well as some information about what numbers were in this chain and how many there were. To do this, I am using the following code:

```
    public static string getLengthCount(long number)
    {
        long current = number;
        bool notFour = true;
        int maxLength = 0;
        string num = "";
        List<int> UsedNums = new List<int>();
        List<List<long>> NumList = new List<List<long>>();
        for (int length = 0; notFour == true && current >= 0; length++)
        {
            int thisLength = getLengthFromLong(current);
            if (HumanFriendlyInteger.IntegerToWritten(current).Length == 4) notFour = false;
            if (UsedNums.Contains(thisLength))
            {
                NumList.Insert(thisLength, new List<long> { current });
            }
            else
            {
                NumList[thisLength].Add(current);
            }
            UsedNums.Add(thisLength);
            if (thisLength >= maxLength)
            {
                num += "," + current;
            }
            maxLength = Math.Max(maxLength, thisLength);
            current--;
        }
        return maxLength + ", by " + NumList[maxLength][0] + " and " + (NumList[maxLength].Count-1) + " more.";
    }
```

However, this gives me the error `Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.`. I've figured out that the error is coming from the `NumList.Insert` line, and think the reason is because I am trying to create an element in the `NumList` list that is over the list's length - The list starts out at length 0, then I add a value at the 5th index, for example.

**The Question:**

Is there any way I can get around this error?

Comment: It looks like you really want a `Dictionary<int, List<int>>` or an `ILookup<int, int>`. After all, you don't have a key 0, key 1, key 2 etc...

Comment: Yep. I'll try using that, and see if it will give me less problems.

Comment: To fix your code, maybe try breaking the for loop at 
`if (HumanFriendlyInteger.IntegerToWritten(current).Length == 4) notFour = false;`. Meaning something like `if (HumanFriendlyInteger.IntegerToWritten(current).Length == 4) { notFour = false; break; }`